# Ansible: How to get the ip of ansible_hosts with shell command?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a `inventory.yaml` file:

```
secondtest:
  hosts:
    host1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.33.168
    host2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.7.151
    host3:
      ansible_host: 192.168.33.158
```

I want to get all ip address and I tried `ansible secondtest -i inventory.yaml --list-hosts` and this is the output:

```
  hosts (3):
    host1
    host2
    host3
```

How can I get the Ips?

Comment: Since that are `hostvars` you could use `ansible-inventory secondtest --graph --vars`.

Comment: Hi @U880D. Thanks for your reply. It works fine. Is there any other method to output only the Ips as a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *ansible-inventory* to list the inventory

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory.yaml --list
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "host1": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.33.168"
            },
            "host2": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.7.151"
            },
            "host3": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.33.158"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped",
            "secondtest"
        ]
    },
    "secondtest": {
        "hosts": [
            "host1",
            "host2",
            "host3"
        ]
    }
}
```

Then you can use, for example, [*jq*](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to select what you want

```bash
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory.yaml --list | jq '._meta.hostvars[].ansible_host'
"192.168.33.168"
"192.168.7.151"
"192.168.33.158"
```